# Converting VBscript to VB Error (checking for right characters)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vbscript

The following code was written in vbscript and I'm in the process of converting over to visual basic.

On the following line: `If Right(LCase(oFile.Name), 3) = "pdf" Then` I get the following error: Variable 'Right' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. Also is says Object variable or With block variable not set.

To my best of knowledge, I believe it is checking to make sure the filenames right 3 characters are "pdf"?

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If Right(LCase(oFile.Name), 3) = "pdf" Then

            Data = Replace(oFile.name, ".pdf", "")
            Data = Replace(oFile.name, ".PDF", "")

            Data = Split(Data, "-")
            acct = Data(1)
            lob = Data(2)

            fileName = clientid & "-" & acct & "-" & lob & "-" & speciesid & "-" & seq & ".pdf"

            outputLine = acct & "," & speciesid & "," & lob & "," & oFile.Name & "," & inputDate

            oOutFile.WriteLine(outputLine)

        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

at the beginning of your program. "Right" is a function in this namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxs6hz0a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I ended up doing this `If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(LCase(oFile.Name), 3) = "pdf" Then` Is one way better per say to use?

Comment: Most people put it at the beginning to have smaller, cleaner code. However it's perfectly acceptable to do it either way.